# how to remove python list cage

Tags: python

Like this, let's assume I have a script like this:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
b = random.choices(a)
print (b)
```

if you run that that will show like this right

```
['*random range a until e']
```

what I want the list change from this `['*random range a until e']` to `'*random range a until we'` can anyone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

random.choices(), returns a LIST, as you can read here - https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_choices.asp

So workaround would be to do it like this:

```
import random
a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
n = random.randint(0, len(a) - 1) # The randint() takes in 2 parameters, the 
#lowest and the highest choice, the highest here is the length of a list
b = a[n]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the letters obtained from [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices).

With the argument `k=<size>` you can specify the length of the generated string.

```py
>>> import random
>>> a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> size = 10
>>> b = "".join(random.choices(a, k=size))
>>> b
'caccbbaade'
```